# Want to create the infowindow for the marker in google map

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I want to create such kind of a marker which will display various info like table getting data from database,image,buttons,labels..etc but I am not able to do so,
So my question is..Is there any other method rather than infowindow which should be opened when I click the respective Marker to perform my task?
,I have also worked on Modal Dailog Box and Also if I am making use of alert box but this is also not helping me,So any suggestion...
Thanking all..

Comment: Why can you not do it with an infoWindow?

Comment: @nunespascal..thanks for rply.....I am neither able to implement table which will take data from database into that infowindow nor all the other requirements as stated above,is there any helping document on my requirement so that I can implement in info window itself...???

Answer (score 1):

[markers with infowindows](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map1.html)

[markers with infowindows from xml](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html)

[markers with infowindows from FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_GViz_infowindows.html)

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a marker does not have to create an infowindow. Clicking the marker triggers and event, and you can decide what happens next. This includes everything you said above

-Getting data from DB
-Displaying images
-Creating or deleting buttons

and much more.

Inside the event listener is where you want to put your new code.